# How to classify users in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                 'x': [ 1.6, 0.5, 0.4, 4.2,  2.6, 1, 1.6, 2.1, 2, 1.2],
                 'y': [ 1.2, 0.3, 0.7, 1.2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                'value': [2.8, 0.8, 1.1, 5.4, 5.6, 4, 4.6, 5.1, 5, 4.2]})
```

[image]

where value is a summation result of x and y.
Now, I want to classify users into two categories (binary classification) based on the column "value" and plot the results of this classification in a plot with line regression like this figure.

[image]

Comment: The term _binary classification_ is normally used to describe a supervised algorithm (you know the categories in advance). What you are looking for seems to be an unsupervised method like the one [mozway proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77448546/15032126). However a _regression_ makes little sense there since there's no independent variable to regress.

Comment: Can you please explain your figure? What's in each axis? You say that you want to classify based on column `values`, but your figure has actually three dimensions: two axes and the class code (stars, circles).

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe use [`KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans)?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

cluster = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(df[['value']]).labels_
# array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)

df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c=np.array(['#3A93D6', '#D6A53A'])[cluster])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, could we add a regression line like in the figure?

Comment: How would you compute it?

Comment: This is a classic support vector machine (SVM) problem. The SVM will find you the support vectors (the closest points in each class from the line of separation), from which the separation line (what OP calls the regression line) can be computed

Comment: @inspectorG4dget This is an unsupervised problem since the two categories are not defined in the dataset.

Comment: Unless of course you assume the results of KMeans as ground truth and try to regress to it... but it should be clear what the OP wants to do with this. A voronoi diagram from the centroids will do the job of separating the space of categories.

Comment: ok fair enough. I must have misunderstood OP. I assumed OP had class labels `based on the column "value"`. K-Means makes sense in this case